# Div displays differently in IE and Chrome

Tags: html

Something very strange is happening when displaying a div. In IE, it displays like it's supposed to, but in Chrome it is shifted down slightly. 
Here's what it looks like in IE:

[image]

And in Chrome:

[image]

You will notice that in chrome the content div is shifted down slightly. Why is Chorme doing this?

Here is my code:

```
<?php include "headermysql.php"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function to_login_page()
{
window.location.assign("http://127.0.0.1/sxp/login.php");
}
function to_signup_page()
{
window.location.assign("http://127.0.0.1/sxp/signup.php");
}
</script>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "textstyles.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php include "headerhtml.php";?>
<div class = "menu">
<p>menu</p>
</div>
<div class = "content">
<?php
//irrelevant PHP code

?>
<a class = "main" href = "post.php">Post new topic</a>
</div>
<div class = "footer">
<p class = "footer">Copyright imulsion 2013</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
div.header
{
height:150px;
background-color:#008AC8;
}
div.menu
{
float:left;
width:200px;
height:800px;
background-color:#64BCE2
}
div.content
{
height:800px;
background-color:#F9F9D9;
}
div.footer
{
height:20px;
background-color:#008AC8;
}
```

Comment: can you post some css?

Comment: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: @kellyjohnson sorry, have edited

Comment: Can you post headerhtml.php?

Comment: we can't help without the CSS

Comment: I think there is a margin causing it in some of the code we don't have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it's the <p> element, it often has an implicit margin or padding.  Try the "developer tools" - both IE and Chrome have their own versions, and verify if that's the problem or not.  If so, then either remove the <p> tag or add a rule to remove the margin and padding and set them exactly as @Stacey Garrison suggests except for the p instead of body and html.

Comment: putting margin:0;padding:0;in my main <p> styling worked. Thank you!

Comment: ah yep that's what it would be. You still need a reset.css because there are lots of implicit styles like this in Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a css reset, as Oded posted. There are a lot of them out there:

I use this one: http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Simplest solution though is to try this:

```
body, html {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: uh...nope, didn't work. The webpage just got slightly bigger.

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't actually see the problem correctly. I thought you were referring to the white border around the whole thing. One second I will look at the real problem.

Comment: Strange. It certainly looks like padding or a margin on the `body` tag.

Comment: There's also a gap between the beige body content and the header, but we don't have the header's html

Answer (score -1):

Every web browser interprets code a little bit differently.  You will just have to play around with the code, and see what happens in different scenarios.  Right click and press "inspect element" on both IE and Chrome.  This will help you narrow down to the problem.