# How to let IE have a auto blank on the top of p tag just like Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

allo, I have a CSS div problem in IE.

The problem is [the reverse version of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740607/div-displays-differently-in-ie-and-chrome)
.

My question is, is there any way besides reset CSS can I do to let IE have a auto blank on the top of p tag just like Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: Just set the body's margin to `20px`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use css

```
p {
padding-top:15px;
}
```