# Site displays different when debugging in VS2012 with IE and when in production

Tags: asp.net, debugging, responsive-design, internet-explorer-11

I'm working on a asp.net project that is a responsive website so it can be viewed on mobile and tablets.  When running the project the site opens in IE 11 and looks great.  When I publish the site and open it with IE 11 the div that holds the main content is dropped to the next line.

What am I missing to publish or set to have this correct?  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you're developing on ASP.net you might be using IIS, such is a web server which I don't know a lot about.

My idea is that you are probably missing configuration changes from development to production mode of your web server.

Hope it will point you to the right direction.

Comment: Thank you hurricane.  I just posted the answer.  It was a compatibility view setting I had to turn off.    I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the steps to find the answer here:

[Div displays differently in IE and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740607/div-displays-differently-in-ie-and-chrome)

I went into the developer tools and Console and there it said that it was being displayed in Compatibility View.  I checked the settings and sure enough the url was listed.  I removed it and refreshed and everything is looking good.